# nohup job control rhel6/centos

Tags: bash, passenger, rhel6

I have a question about UNIX job control in RHEL6

Basically, I am trying to implement passenger debug log rotation using logrotate.  I am following the instructions here:

https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger-and-logrotation

I've got everything setup correctly (I think).  My problem is this; when I spawn the background job using

```
nohup pipetool $HOME/passenger.log < $HOME/passenger.pipe &
```

And then log out and back in, if I inspect the process table, for example by using 'ps aux' if I check the pid of the process it appears as with the command 'bash'.  I have tried changing the first line of the command to "#!/usr/bin/ruby".  Here is an example of this:

```
[root@server]# nohup pipetool /var/log/nginx/passenger-debug.log < /var/pipe/passenger.pipe &
[1] 63767
[root@server]# exit
exit
[me@server]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for me: 
[root@server]# ps aux | grep 63767
root     63767  0.0  0.0 108144  2392 pts/0    S    15:26   0:00 bash
root     63887  0.0  0.0 103236   856 pts/0    S+   15:26   0:00 grep 63767
[root@server]#
```

When this occurs the line in the supplied logrotate file ( killall -HUP pipetool ) fails because the 'pipetool' is not matched.  Again, I've tried changing the first line to #!/usr/bin/ruby.  This had no impact.  So, my question is basically; is there any good way to have the actual command appear in the process table instead of just 'bash' when spawned using job control?  I am using bash as the shell when I invoke the pipetool.  I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: depending on your OS, etc. try looking for `ptree $PID`, or a visual tree option to ps. You should then see the parent `bash` process as well as it's children processes. Why can't you just search for `passenger` hmmm.... or `pipetool` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you: edit `pipetool` to set the global variable `$PROGRAM_NAME`:

```
$PROGRAM_NAME = 'pipetool'
```

The script should then show up as `pipetool` in the process list.